# Show / Hide Buttons in GridView dynamically - ASP.NET c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a Gridview (connected to a Datasource), in the first column is a flag which is either a 1 or a 0.  I want to add a column with a button.

If the flag in column one = 1 then the button should say 'Hide', if the flag is 0 it should say 'Show'.

I need it to do this for all rows in the gridview

Can someone give me some pointers? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In button control's property, add

```
Visible='<%# Eval(flag) == 1%>'
```

Answer (score 0):

On the button I set the visible to true or false if the my_flag was of a particular value

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSwitchOff" CssClass="btn btn-warning" runat="server" Text="Switch Off" Visible='<%# Eval("my_flag").ToString() == "0" ? true : false%>' />

<asp:Button ID="btnSwitchOn" CssClass="btn btn-info" runat="server" Text="Switch Off" Visible='<%# Eval("my_flag").ToString() == "1" ? true : false%>' />
```